# JSON Fetch returns undefined when consulting a object

Tags: javascript, json, object, async-await, es6-promise

I have a pricing table with variable plans. When an user configure your plan, the href of button is updated according with a `json` file. The code stores each plan variables and return the correct link throught an `array` of `objects`.

Here is the JSON Example;

```
[{
   "planName": "PRO",
    "links": {
        "monthly": {
            "plan1": "https://example.com", 
            "plan2": "https://example.org"
        },
        "yearly": {
            "plan1": "https://example.net", 
            "plan2": "https://example.com"
        }
    }
}]
```

I get the fetched data, but my object returns `undefined` and i can't  get monthly > plan 1 informations, for example.

Bellow is the code.

```js
function changeLinkWithJSON() {
  var planDuration = document.querySelector('[data-type]').attributes[0].nodeValue;
  var planName = document.querySelector('[plan]').innerHTML;
  var planRef = 'plan1';
  var button = document.querySelector('.select');
  var num;
  if (planName == 'PRO') {
    num = 0
  };
  if (planName == 'PLATINUM') {
    num = 1
  };

  async function getPlanData() {
    let response = await fetch("/plans.json");
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }

  getPlanData()
    .then(data => console.log(data[num].links.planDuration));

}
changeLinkWithJSON();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-type="monthly">
    <h2 plan>PRO</h2>
    <a class="select" class="plan-link" href="#">Buy Plan</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can i return the expected results instead undefined?

Comment: I don't see `planDuration` in the JSON.

Comment: You shouldn't make up your own attributes like `plan`. You should use `data-XXX` for all custom attributes.

Comment: @Barmar. Returns undefined. `planDuration` select the attribute in HTML and return "montly or yearly".

Comment: `.planDuration` should be `[planDuration]` to use the value of the variable.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks for advice. i'll modify the attributes. This question is just an exapmle.

Comment: Different writing in "montly" and "monthly". And there are two class-attributes on the a-tag.

Comment: @Barmar. Bracket notation didn't worked on planDuration. i writed  `data[num].links.[planDuration]` on console. Expecting to return `data[0].links.monthly` @dipser . Snippet fixed

Comment: Not `.[planDuration]` just `[planDuration]`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `.attributes[0]`, I don't think you can rely on the order of attributes. Use `.getAttribute("data-type")`

Comment: @bramar Using just `[planDuration]` solved the problem. Thanks! I'm also fixing the `.getAttribute("data-type") `.